# How far out were the story themes of the "12 Monkeys" TV series planned?

Tags: 12-monkeys-2015

I have just finished watching the *12 Monkeys* TV series. It seems pretty well put together with, from what I can tell, most of the timeline story arcs pulled together.

Have the writers ever talked about the creation of the show, was this a *Babylon 5* story arc, with long term threads planned out in advance. A clear idea of where the story was going and the aims and background of the main antagonists.

Or was this more a *Battle Star Galactica* with stories being created on the fly and made to fit what had been written before with no clear plan for how it would all end up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ending (or at least a significant part of it) was purportedly planned from very early on.

Showrunner Terry [Matalas](https://twitter.com/terrymatalas/status/1012890916481167360) [has](https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/12-monkeys-showrunner-terry-matalas-has-always-been-able-to-see-the-future) [repeatedly](https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/12-monkeys-showrunner-terry-matalas-breaks-down-series-finale-philosophy-of-time-travel) [professed](https://www.fandom.com/articles/12-monkeys-showrunner-breaks-down-powerful-series-finale) that much of the show was mapped out from the beginning, and that that is how he prefers television shows. For example:

> I always knew what I wanted the last scene to be, in the series. So [we were] just kind of leading up to there.

> "I always knew that Cole would seemingly be erased but that the surprise would be he found his way back to Cassie in its last moments," Matalas said.

> I’ve known it was Hannah since Season 1. I first came up with the idea — I don’t know why — I just remember working on Season 1 Episode 12, I knew that I wanted to bring Hannah in during Season 2. And how crazy would it be if she was in fact his mother. Brooke William’s first day on set, I told her.